# how to split an array at a certain point in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Say you have this:

```
["10:00 PM", "10:15 PM", "10:30 PM", "10:45 PM", "11:00 PM"]
```

I would like to split or explode this array at `"10:30 PM"` and grab the remaining array:

```
["10:45 PM", "11:00 PM"]
```

Any ideas?

I could iterate through it and then match each result then build another array, i was thinking if there is a "built in" way.

Comment: I guess this is not precisely a duplicate, since the question is to remove elements up to and including one with a particular value, rather than removing one or some fixed number of elements from the beginning.

Comment: This question asks how to remove the first two elements, the dupe asks about removing one, and shows multiple approaches that could help the OP if he's ready to think a little.

Comment: If he was ready to think a little, he wouldn't have posted the question in the first place. Anyway, the questions **doesn't** ask how to remove the first two elements, it asks how to remove the elements up to and including the one with value "10:30 PM".

Comment: Actually, it does ask how to remove the first two elements ;-) As the OP said himself, he knows how to iterate through the array to find the matching element.  He's looking for the correct builtin method to remove elements from the beginning of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var times = ["10:00 PM", "10:15 PM", "10:30 PM", "10:45 PM", "11:00 PM"];

// without altering the array
var newTimes = times.slice(times.indexOf("10:30 PM") + 1);

// or, altering the array
times.splice(times.indexOf("10:30 PM") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

@sahbeewah's solution is good, another (destructive) possibility is

```
while (array.pop() !== '10:30 PM") { }
```

although you would also need to handle non-happy cases.

We could write a generalized analog to `String#split` using `Array#reduce` as follows:

```
function split_array(arr, delim) {
    return arr.reduce(function(result, elt) {
        if (delim === elt) {
            result.push([]);
        } else {
            result[result.length-1].push(elt);
        }
        return result;
    }, [[]]);
 }
```

Then

```
split_array(times, "10:30 PM") // [["10:00 PM", "10:15 PM"], ["10:45 PM", "11:00 PM"]]
```

so our result is `split_array(times, "10:30 PM")[1]`.

An obvious extension would be to pass a function in place of `delim` to specify more general "delimiters".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to do that..  like

```js
var array = ["10:00 PM", "10:15 PM", "10:30 PM", "10:45 PM", "11:00 PM"];
var index = array.indexOf('10:30 PM');
var part2 = array.splice(index + 1);

console.log(array, part2)
```